# com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value:

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc

Would there be any wise person who would be able to answer me why when I'm trying to build this object and to send it to my database:

```
final Customer customer = Customer.builder().name("John").surname("Smith").dateOfBirth(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(1980,10,10))).build();
entityServiceFactory.createEntity(customer);
```

I end up getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '1960' for column 'dateOfBirth' at row 1
```

Does anybody know how to solve that difficulty?

Comment: Can you share the Entity class?

Comment: You specify a date in 1980 and get 1960 in the error message, 20 years earlier, is it correct?

Comment: @OleV.V. That is exactly what it happens, it gives me the error message with a difference of 20 years.